# How to get Ticks in system date?

Tags: sql-server

I need Ticks in Current date time, just print the Ticks only.

```
set @date = GETDATE();
```

I need this format output:

> Ticks - 634513824000000000

Comment: SQL-Server doesn't support this precision.It stores time to 1/300th of a second, whereas a single tick is one ten-millionth of a second.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question properly format your code sample and the output - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You won't get precission you want. See: [@@TIMETICKS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187738.aspx)

> Returns the number of microseconds per tick.
>
> The amount of time per tick is computer-dependent. Each tick on the operating system is 31.25 milliseconds, or one thirty-second of a second.

```
SELECT @@TIMETICKS

-- result: 31250
```